# Haskell performance when using classes and instances

Tags: performance, haskell, tuples, benchmarking, instantiation

**The Problem**

I want to simulate in Haskell a multivalue outputting functions. The Haskell code is generated (not hand written) - this is important information, see below:

This can be of course easly done by returning a tuple from function, like

```
f x y = (x+y, x-y)
```

But when using such function I have to know what kind of tuple it returns:

```
...
(out_f_1, out_f_2)          = f a b
(out_g_1, out_g_2, out_g_3) = g out_f_1
...
```

And so on ... But while generating code, I don't know what is the type of ouput of lets say f, so right now I'm using the `Data.List.Select` package and simulate the above with:

```
import Data.List.Select
...
out_f = f a b
out_g = g (sel1 outf)
...
```

The problem is the performance - on my testing program, the version, which uses `Data.List.Select` is twice slower than the version written by hand.

This is very obvious situation, because `Data.List.Select` is written using `classes` and `instances`, so it uses some kind of runtime dictionary (If I'm not wrong).
(http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/tuple/0.2.0.1/doc/html/src/Data-Tuple-Select.html#sel1)

**The Question**

I want to ask you If is it possible to somehow compile the version (which uses `Data.List.Select`) to be as fast as the manually crafted one?

I think there should be a switch to compiler, which will tell him to "instantiate" the classes and interfaces for each use (something like templates from C++).

**Benchmarks**

Test1.hs:

```
import qualified Data.Vector as V
import System.Environment
b :: Int -> Int
b x = x + 5
c x = b x + 1
d x = b x - 1
a x = c x + d x
main = do
   putStrLn "Starting..."
   args <- getArgs
   let iternum = read (head args) :: Int in do
      putStrLn $ show $ V.foldl' (+) 0 $ V.map (\i -> a (iternum-i))
         $ V.enumFromTo 1 iternum
      putStrLn "Done."
```

compile with `ghc -O3 Test1.hs`

Test2.hs:

```
import qualified Data.Vector as V
import Data.Tuple.Select
import Data.Tuple.OneTuple

import System.Environment
b x = OneTuple $ x + 5
c x = OneTuple $ (sel1 $ b x) + 1
d x = OneTuple $ (sel1 $ b x) - 1
a x = OneTuple $ (sel1 $ c x) + (sel1 $ d x)
main = do
   putStrLn "Starting..."
   args <- getArgs
   let iternum = read (head args) :: Int in do
      putStrLn $ show $ V.foldl' (+) 0 $ V.map (\i -> sel1 $ a (iternum-i))
         $ V.enumFromTo 1 iternum
      putStrLn "Done."
```

compile with `ghc -O3 Test2.hs`

**Results**

```
time ./Test1 10000000 = 5.54 s
time ./Test2 10000000 = 10.06 s
```

Comment: The two benchmarks perform the same for me. In both cases, they produce tail recursive loops operating on unboxed integers. One possibility for the perceived difference in performance is that your second benchmark is more affected by the additional pointer indirections due to wrapping everything in `OneTuple`, since GHC could easily elide the typeclass dictionaries in this case.

Comment: @sabauma - ok, I've got it! My tests were not compiled using `-O3` flag (because I was compiling without `-force-recompile`) so GHC didn't make such optimizations. Could you please tell me why we should anytime use `specialize pragma` if compiler is able to optimize such expressions like this?

Comment: this is a fairly easy example for the compiler to optimize. GHC can elide the typeclass lookups in this case because it is able to inline the polymorphic calls and determine which typeclass instance to use at compile time. You cannot (or do not want to) always inline large function, in which case, it is still advantageous for GHC to produce a specialized version of the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the results I've posted are not accurate - as @sabauma told - the two codes perform in the same time If you compile them with optimizations enabled.

The @tohava's answer is very good if you want to explicity show which functions to specialize (see the @sabauma comment above).

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure, but it might be worthwhile to try 
http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.0.3/html/users_guide/pragmas.html#specialize-pragma